# Buttons do no action in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on a web application using PrimeFaces, JPA, Hibernate and JSF 2.0.

I have this JSF page, the "Save" and "cancel" `p:commandButton` do no action! Can you help, please ?

The action (`action="#{lotController.initLot}"`) in the `p:commandButton`in `action="#{lotController.initLot}"` redirect to this page:

```
<h:body style="width:600px; ">
<ui:composition template="/common/master-layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">#{message['app.page.main.title']}</ui:define>
    <ui:debug
        rendered="#{initParam['javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE'] eq 'Development'}"
        hotkey="x" />
    <ui:define name="content">

        <p:fieldset legend="Création d'un nouveau lot"
            style="margin-top: 20px;">

            <h:form id="addLotForm">

                <p:fieldset legend="Lots techniques" toggleable="true"
                    toggleSpeed="500"
                    style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; background-color:RGB(225,240,233)">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText value="Libellé" style="font-weight:bold" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{lotController.lotToSave.libelle}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:fieldset>

                <!-- Descriptifs -->
                <p:fieldset legend="Descriptifs" toggleable="true"
                    toggleSpeed="500"
                    style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; background-color:RGB(225,240,233)">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText value="Libellé" style="font-weight:bold" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{lotController.selectedDescriptif}"
                            effect="fade" converter="#{descriptifConverter}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lotController.listDescriptifs}" var="descriptif"
                                itemLabel="#{descriptif.libelle}" itemValue="#{descriptif}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:fieldset>

                <p:commandButton value="Save" id="saveLot"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
                    action="#{lotController.createLot}"
                    style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;height:125%;width:70px">
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancelLot"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
                    action="#{lotController.cancelLot}"
                    style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;height:125%;width:70px" />
            </h:form>
        </p:fieldset>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The index.xhtml:

```
        <h:form id="listLotsForm">
            <p:panel>
                <ui:include src="lotDataTable.xhtml" />
            </p:panel>

        </h:form>
```

The lotDataTable.xhtml:

```
                <p:commandButton value="Ajouter un lot" id="addLot"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
                    action="#{lotController.initLot}"
                    style="margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;height:125%;width:140px" />

            <p:dataTable id="dataTableLot" var="lot" resizableColumns="true"
                liveResize="true" paginator="true"
                value="#{lotController.listLots}" rows="10" scrollable="false"
                style="width: 100%" selection="#{lotController.selectedLot}"
                rowKey="#{lot.idLot}"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" editable="true">


                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{lotController.onEdit}"
                    update=":listLotsForm:messages" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{lotController.onCancel}"
                    update=":listLotsForm:messages" />
                    update=":listLotsForm:messages" /> -->

                <p:column headerText="N° lot" style="width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lot.idLot}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Libellé" style="width: 100px">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{lot.libelle}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{lot.libelle}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:6%">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:6%">
                    <p:commandButton action="#{lotController.deleteLot(lot)}"
                        icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Supprimer" />
                </p:column>


            </p:dataTable>
```

The Controler:

```
public String createLot(){
    LotDto lot = prepareDtoBeforeSave();
    LotDto lotCreated = lotService.create(lot);
    clearLot();
    init();
    return "/views/administration/parametres/lot/listeLots?faces-redirect=true";
}

protected LotDto prepareDtoBeforeSave() {
    LotDto lot = new LotDto();
    lot.setIdDescriptif(selectedDescriptif);
    lot.setLibelle(lotToSave.getLibelle());
    return lot;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure?`<p:commandButton>` has in-built `ajax` functionality. Try setting `ajax=false` on commandButton

Comment: Looks like you have a validation or conversion error while submitting your form. Add a `<h:messages>` to your form to see the errors when submitting the form.

Comment: @SRy when I added `ajax=false` I got this error `Cannot remove the same component twice: j_idt12:j_id2`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I haven't any error message!

Comment: Are you sure you're not nesting `<h:form>` that comes from your template file?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I edited my post. I deleted the second form, after that, converter not executing and I obtain Null in the DB

Comment: I would recommend trying to isolate the problem first. This means, create a single page with the components that gives you problem. Try to reproduce the problem there. If this doesn't happen, then the problem is somewhere in the current design you have, probably by nesting forms or something else.

Comment: If your buttons aren't calling Action then the JSF lifecycle is halting due to a Converter or Validator error somewhere else in the same form as the button. Set a breakpoint on the converters and validators which you've signed up to the Form properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all.

I solved the problem, I forgot to generate hashCode() and equals() methods for my converter.